# How to strip function names from a C++ production binary in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, symbols, debug-symbols

I've been debugging a crash in my C++ binary, built for Release build configuration in Xcode. It was running on a client computer, so the .dSYM file was not available. There was only the binary itself.

The binary was built for a Release build configuration. (I didn't change any other build settings in the Xcode project for it.)

But the crash report in the .ips file gave me names of my functions:

```
Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   MyApp      0x10252e678 MyClass::doWriteHere(char*) + 18
1   MyApp      0x10252e4e0 MyClass::performSomeFunction() + 42
2   MyApp      0x10252e2b4 MyClass::DoWork(WORK_TYPE) + 998
3   MyApp      0x10252d950 main + 1190
4   dyld       0x1937e4f28 start + 2246
```

How do I strip those from my production, or release binary?

EDIT: Changing "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" to NO or YES makes no difference on the presence of the function symbol names in the production binary.

Does it blindly include function names into the binary thinking that `C++` `==` `Objective-C`?

Comment: The `strip` command can remove debug symbols (and other stuff), but not sure you can get rid of function names.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I think the Xcode project already has "strip style: all symbols" enabled. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I meant the command line `strip` command. But, as I said; not sure you can easily get rid of function names.  Of course you could get *complicated* and encrypt your executable on disk, then write a small loader that would decrypt it into memory when run, but that's going to be a real pain.You could  also write a clang tool to process your source code and change function names into random strings before compiling, but that's also a bother. Why is function names showing up so bad?

Comment: If you manage to achieve this (which is probably not possible), how are you going to analyse crash reports?

Comment: @PaulSanders by using the .dSYM (symbols) file. How else? That is how Visual Studio compiler works. Does Xcode not work the same way? Placing symbol names into a binary is .... I won't use any bad words.

Comment: Yes, it's doable.  `atos` is your friend.

Comment: @PaulSanders `xcrun atos` allows you to symbolicate a crash log. I am not asking for that. I need to remove symbols from the compiled binary file. There must be some Xcode project build setting that I'm missing.

Comment: You might get somewhere by running `strip` as an explicit build phase.  Xcode's build log should show you the arguments being passed to it, you could take a look to see if it supports any others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `Deployment Postprocessing` setting in the Xcode project that needs to be enabled for the "release" build to remove private symbols. For some reason it is not enabled by default in the latest version of Xcode. ([Source](https://dennisbabkin.com/blog/?t=macos-programming-xcode-build-schemes-diagnose-memory-corruption-and-crashes#dbg_w_crash_log))